# How to remove a picklist from a record type?

Tags: picklist, record-type

I have 10 Picklists Available for Editing for Record Type 1. So how do I remove Picklist X from Record Type 1.

[image]

I have added a screenshot. I can't find the option to remove a picklist from a record type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't ***remove*** the pick-list from the RecordType per-say.

What you can do

- Hide the pick-list on the page layout associated with that
  RecordType.
- Remove all pick-list options from the pick-list for that particular
  RecordType *(click edit on the screen have captured above, and remove all options)*

Comment: I tried the second option. But it requires at least one value to be present

Comment: Thanks @chris-duncombe. It's never late to say thank you :)